# I have installed the magento2 successfully but there are a lot of js error

Tags: magento, magento2

I have installed the magento2 successfully but there are a lot of js error.

When see the console log through the firebug it shows a lot of errors and is there any thing else to config for the magento css and js.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved ...

There is a 'cache' system for these static resources.
navigate to the folder dev/tools/Magento/Tools/View

Run the below command in the terminal

php deploy.php

After running this command css and other files created under the Pub/static/ folder and all the css will appear and page look fine.

Comment: i dont have View folder inside this path dev/tools/Magento/Tools/ what to do?

Comment: i have same problem

Answer (score 6):

try following :

1. make bin/magento executable

   ```
   chmod +x bin/magento
   ```
2. Clear cache etc in var folder

   ```
   rm -rf var/cache/ var/di/ var/generation/ var/page_cache/
   ```
3. Run Setup ( if any thing missing )

   ```
   bin/magento setup:upgrade
   ```
4. Deploy Static Content

   ```
   bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
   ```
5. Give Permission to var & pub folders

   ```
   chmod -R 777 pub/ var/
   ```

now all the static files containing js, css etc will be deployed in pub/static folder

Answer (score 3):

Remove all files and folder in pub/static except .htaccess and then run:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Hello just tried that and got the following


root@cloud [/home/thepurpl]# cd public_html
root@cloud [/home/thepurpl/public_html]# php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found in /home/thepurpl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Bundle/DataBundle.php on line 64
root@cloud [/home/thepurpl/public_html]#

Answer (score 1):

You can try after giving full permission to magento folder

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I've deleted `.htaccess` file from `pub/static` folder by mistake.

I copied the file from the original installation to `pub/static` directory.