# Magento 2 not loading CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, css, magento2

I have installed magento 2 successfully on localhost but I am not able to see admin panel as it render 404 error to me.

Secondly, When I open front-end then CSS and JavaScript is not loading.They also renders 404 errors.

Also When I try to run command:

```
{your Magento install dir}/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

I got the following error

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                              
There are no commands defined in the "setup:static-content" namespace.
```

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492838/installing-magento-2-does-not-deploy-the-pub-static-frontend-and-backend/32011650#32011650

Answer (score 19):

This One Worked for Me.
use this Command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Step 1 : In CMD Open your root directory using cd command

Step 2 : `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` - run this Command

then,Check Your `pub/static` folder, CSS and Js files will be available there

Refer  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646623/i-have-installed-the-magento2-successfully-but-there-are-alot-of-js-error)

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem and when i follow your istruction at step 2 I get: "Magento supports PHP 5.5.0 or later. Please read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html" BUT i have PHP 5.5.27 on my server!!! Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 16):

**Here is the simplest solution if showing version name in css path**

like : pub/static/version323334/

then run this query in my sql

```
 INSERT INTO core_config_data (path, value) 
VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;
```

after that clear the config cache

```
 bin/magento cache:clean config
```

you can also disable static file version form admin

[image]

Comment: This one resolved the issue of https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21201. After this may need to perform 

sudo rm -rf pub/static
sudo rm -rf var/cache
sudo rm -rf var/composer_home
sudo rm -rf var/generation
sudo rm -rf var/page_cache
sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed
sudo php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Your answer is more easy to follow and it works!

Comment: Yesssss it's work for me 
Thanks !!!

Answer (score 6):

Try the same command as root user by adding sudo like below

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 3):

Though it is old question, its answers could not help me to fix my issue what would generate same error message. I suggest the followings:

1. At first, you can find its underlying cause. In your magento2 directory, find magento error as follows:

> tail var/log/system.log

Or find if there is any error in php error log file

*If you find isolated error, fix it.*

2. If no error is found, do the followings. Remove generate folder by executing the following commands:

> ```
> sudo rm -rf pub/static
> sudo rm -rf var/cache
> sudo rm -rf var/composer_home
> sudo rm -rf var/generation
> sudo rm -rf var/page_cache
> sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed
> ```

After deleting them, you can re-create them by executing the following commands:

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 3):

Changing `dev/static/sign` to `0` in core config data worked for me

then,

```
bin/magento cache:flush
```

then,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 2):

We also faced this issue once, and sorted it out. For this you need to go directly in `bin` directory and use that command. For example,

```
php magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Some times if you run this command outside of `bin` or from any directory

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

then you will get error like (may be it is because of linux system),

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
  There are no commands defined in the "setup:static-content" namespace.
```

**Update:**

If any `*.xml` file in our custom modules is not valid then the same error will come.

Answer (score 1):

I also had same issue and below step solves my issue:

> Step 1: Navigate to  directory where magento is installed. 
>   Step 2: Run  "sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy"

Comment: This worked for me, as there were apparently permission issues with /pub/

Answer (score 1):

Provide static deploy command like this:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Please set full permission for pub and var folders.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands in CLI interface of your Magento2 root folder:

```
$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
$ php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Then delete var folder by this command at your root of magento2.

```
$ rm -rf var/*
```

Then refresh your homepage and admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing theming issue after Installation in Magento 2. You can follow these steps :

1. Run this query:

   INSERT INTO core_config_data (path, value) VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;
2. For local machine run this query:

   UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = '0' WHERE
   `core_config_data`.`path` LIKE  '%web/seo/use_rewrites%';
3. Remove all the files from pub and var directory:

   sudo rm -rf var/di var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/cache/
   pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs/
   pub/static/deployed_version.txt
4. Give Permission to var and pub directories of your project:

   sudo chmod -R 777 var/* pub/*
5. Upgrade Setup:

   sudo bin/magento setup:upgrade
6. Deploy content:

   sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

After these steps, you will be able to see proper theme.

Answer (score 1):

After trying all the solutions mentioned over here and in https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder

We were not able to get this thing going.

But this is very weird answer but it worked for us.

Firstly, We cleared the cache and ensured that the static files are being created inside pub/static/ folder.
Then checked the deployed_version.txt contains same version number as being loaded in the URL.

Our main culprit was the .htaccess file which was present in pub folder. There should be just one .htaccess file inside pub/static folder but not in pub folder.
This did the trick for us after searching everywhere.

Hope it helps others looking for the similar answer.

Comment: Yes! After two hours of debugging this issue you finally fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you facing problem of css and design after installation in Windows, follow these steps

1. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
2. `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
3. make sure apache "rewrite_module" is enable and then restart the server
4. delete cache folder under `var/cache`

Answer (score 0):

you just need to run this command on your Terminal

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Make sure you give the the root path of your magento in terminal and then run the above command

Answer (score 0):

Just Open the

MAGENTO_ROOT/app/etc/di.xml

and replace below code form line number 574

`<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>`

TO

`<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>`

**DELETE**

> MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/static/_requirejs
>
> MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/static/adminhtml
>
> MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/static/frontend

Answer (score 0):

Just simple and right solution, hope usefull.

Go to your wampserver icon and click on it and than

1. **Apache->apache modules->rewrite_module[enable this]**

After this re-start all services and check it .

Answer (score 0):

The following answer works for me, thanks:

open file MAGENTO_ROOT/app/etc/di.xml

and replace below code form line number 574

Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink

with

Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy

DELETE

```
MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/static/_requirejs

MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/static/adminhtml

MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/static/frontend
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you have not setup permission correctly. It can't see that the command actually exist.

Try running:

`sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;  && sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
sudo chown -R $(whoami):www-data .`

Change www-data to appropriate webserver user. e.g. apache or www-data.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1) Static content deploy. Run the below command from Magento 2 root directory:

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

2) Clear everything in `var/cache` directory or flush the Magento 2 cache using the below command:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

3) Set proper permissions for Magento 2 directories by executing the below command from Magento 2 root directory:

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It says "Access forbidden! Error 403"

Answer (score 0):

I just do

`rm -rf var/di`

then it works again.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens because of failed compilation in the `var/di` folder. You can solve it by deleting everything in your var folder.

Also for future, don't forget that magento command line implements symfony verbosity levels: append `--v` or `---v` to your command to see the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps below to get rid of this issues.

1) Download the Magento 2.

2) Extract this in your www OR htdocs directory.

3) Install the magento. Do not use **localhost**, use **127.0.0.1** in store url and admin url.

**4) After successful installation DO NOT RUN MAGENTO.**

5) Now delete the cache / session of magento 2. Go to the below mentioned paths and delete the files.

```
Magento Root > var > cache > Delete all files

Magento Root > var > page_cache > Delete all files

Magento Root > var > session > Delete all files
```

6) Change the behavior of symlinks for some static resources as mentioned below:-

When Magento 2 is not in production mode, it will try to create symlinks for some static resources on local server. We have to change that behavior of Magento 2 by going to edit `ROOT > app > etc > di.xml` file. Open up di.xml in your favorite code editor, find the `virtualType name="developerMaterialization"` section. In that section below, you will find an item `<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">` which needs to be modified. You can modify it by changing the following content:

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

To:

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

7) Delete all the files except **.htaccess**

```
Magento Root > pub > static > Delete all files except **.htaccess**
```

ITS DONE. Now you may run the magento Front and Backend URL

Answer (score 0):

> > below Solution worked:
> >      Please un below query in database.
> >      INSERT INTO core_config_data (path, value) VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;
> >      https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder

Answer (score 0):

if you have tried `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` or  any such related commands and the issue is still there. Then you may like to try this.

This fix addresses **No Css and Javascript** and **Admin 404 page** issues after magento installation (v2.3).

**step 1 :** open `httpd.conf`.

**step 2 :** search for

1. `AllowOverride` (may be written as AllowOverride all)
2. `Require` (may be written as Require local)

**in directory section** of this file.

**step 3 :** Change

1. `AllowOverride` to `AllowOverride All`
2. `Require` to `Require All Granted`

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue and i get it resolved using the following procedure.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento c:f
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
sudo chown -r your-website-user:your-website-group
ln -s static pub/static
ln -s media pub/media
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of the above is not working try to set 0 in the below paths in `core_config_data` table

`web/secure/use_in_frontend`

`web/secure/use_in_adminhtml`

Answer (score -1):

If you are facing problem of css and js page load design after installation in magento2

please follow the following step-:

open the terminal and navigate to magento web root

```
 $ cd /var/www/html/magento2
```

Step 1.

```
 $ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Step 2.

```
 $ php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Step 3.

make sure apache “rewrite_module” is enable and then restart the server

Step 4.

```
 $ chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magento2
```

Step 5.

```
 $ chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento2
```

Step 6.

delete cache folder under var/cache

The above step working. I hope this will work for you also.

Let me know if any issue. :)

Comment: Your assuming that their web server runs under www-data. Setting all files to full access is a security issue.